# How to draw small characters using turtle and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

Am trying to create a GUI which reduces shape of the letter on display every time the user clicks on a button. For this i have created a canvas widget in the size i want the grid to be and use turtle to draw the shape manually. It works smoothly for all big letters except when i want a really small letter(0.145 cms x 0.145 cms). I tried to change the turtle shape to a single pixel, that doesnt work either. Any suggestions? am including the code i have build so far. Here are 2 examples:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle


window = tk.Tk()
width_value = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value,height_value))
window.configure(bg = 'white')
window.title('canvas')

x0 = width_value/2
y0 = height_value/2
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,height='8.7c',width='8.7c',bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
canvas.place(x=x0,y=y0,anchor = "center")

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.speed('fastest')

t.penup()
t.setposition(((canvas.winfo_width()/2)-(canvas.winfo_width()/5)),-((canvas.winfo_width()/4)))
t.pendown()
t.shape("circle")
t.turtlesize(stretch_wid = 0.05,stretch_len =0.05,outline = 0.05)


t.pensize(canvas.winfo_width()/5)
t.pencolor("black")

t.left(50)
t.circle((canvas.winfo_width()/2-canvas.winfo_width()/10),-280)
t.penup()

window.mainloop()
```

Here is the image which came out

[image]

but when i try to run the code for smaller letters(which is key for the application am building), am not able to get consistent results. Here is the code to explain

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,height='0.145c',width='0.145c',bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
```

Am pasting the image after cutting it from the original size, the idea is that it is not forming C anymore like it did in bigger size

[image]

how can i make it consistent across sizes?

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting in the smaller size is this:

[image]

We can fiddle with the `steps` argument to `circle()` and get something like:

[image]

But let's look at the math.  If we consider that a pixel is roughly one *point* (1/72 of an inch) in size (+/- 30%), then comparing that to your requested size, we find that you're asking the graphics to draw an open circle within a 4 x 4 pixel square:

[image]

It appears to have done the best job possible within a pixel or two, though its anti-aliasing seems to be getting in the way of recognizing this as a letter.  But turtle's `circle()` method isn't necessarily optimized for what you want to do, and you're free to write your own to better handle your needs.

> I tried to change the turtle shape to a single pixel, that doesnt
> work either.

The turtle's shape doesn't affect its drawing unless you're *stamping*.

Comment: if the problem is with the circle method, I tried using turtle.shape as "blank" as well, doesnt change the graphics. Any suggestions on how i can make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching from centimeters to pixels directly, updating

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,height='0.145c',width='0.145c',bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
```

to

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,height=10,width=10,bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: my application needs precision in width and height, hence in cms

Answer (score 0):

Increase Drawing Resolution, use Vector Graphics, and implement antialiasing to smooth out the edges of the drawn shapes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

def draw_small_letter():
    # Your drawing code for small letters here
    pass

window = tk.Tk()
width_value = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))
window.configure(bg='white')
window.title('Canvas')

x0 = width_value / 2
y0 = height_value / 2
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height='8.7c', width='8.7c', bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
canvas.place(x=x0, y=y0, anchor="center")

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.speed('fastest')

# Adjust the canvas size and Turtle's scale for smaller letters
canvas_size_small_letters = 50  # You can experiment with this value
t.penup()
t.setposition(-canvas_size_small_letters / 2, -canvas_size_small_letters / 4)
t.pendown()

# Increase the scaling for smaller letters
t.turtlesize(stretch_wid=0.1, stretch_len=0.1, outline=0.1)

t.pensize(canvas_size_small_letters / 5)
t.pencolor("black")

t.left(50)
t.circle(canvas_size_small_letters / 2 - canvas_size_small_letters / 10, -280)
t.penup()

# Call the function to draw smaller letters
draw_small_letter()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This makes sense, but what if i want precision in the width, height and thickness of the characters even when it is really small?